# CSS absolute positioning and resizing windows

Tags: html, css, css-position

First off let me say, I don't do a whole lot of front end design so please excuse all my inline code etc...

I've built these check boxes to be able to include the image when clicked. I understand it's not inside the parent class but i'm a bit confused at this point on how to move forward. Since it doesn't have a parent class it just looks for the whole web page as it's parent class i presume.

Fairly simple, i think; when i minimize my screen my label positioning removes itself from the boxes and floats off. I'll attach screen shots for more clarity.

I've tried to put a few of them in divs with some success but i'm not 100% sure the right way of doing this and that's why i'm here. I've tried some relative positioning as well.

```
<div class="interests">
<div class="subHeader">Interests:</div>

<label style="background-color: #000; color:#fff; width:160px; font-family: 'itc_avant_garde_gothic_ltbold';
    font-size: 18px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block; z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 465px; top: 1105px;"><div style="position:relative;left:10px; bottom: 8px;">SKATE</div></label>

<label style="background-color: #000; color:#fff; width:160px; font-family: 'itc_avant_garde_gothic_ltbold';
    font-size: 18px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block; z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 685px; top: 1105px;"><div style="position:relative;left:10px; bottom: 8px;">SURF</div></label>

<label style="background-color: #000; color:#fff; width:160px; font-family: 'itc_avant_garde_gothic_ltbold';
    font-size: 18px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block; z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 906px; top: 1105px;"><div style="position:relative;left:10px; bottom: 8px;">SNOW</div></label>

<label style="background-color: #000; color:#fff; width:160px; font-family: 'itc_avant_garde_gothic_ltbold';
    font-size: 18px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block; z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 465px; top: 1300px;"><div style="position:relative;left:10px; bottom: 8px;"> WOMEN</div></label>


<label style="background-color: #000; color:#fff; width:160px; font-family: 'itc_avant_garde_gothic_ltbold';
    font-size: 18px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block; z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 685px; top: 1300px;"><div style="position:relative;left:10px; bottom: 8px;"> MUSIC/ART </div></label>

<label style="position: relative; top: 90px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox.A address.Sk" style="z-index: 1;position: relative; top:4px;">Skate<img src="https://stuff/Images/thumb.jpg" style="position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0;height: 185px;width: 205px;">
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.A address.Sk" value="off">


<label style="position: relative; left:140px; top: 90px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox.A address.Su" style="z-index: 1;position: relative; top:4px;">Surf<img src="https://stuff/Images/thumb.jpg" style="position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0;height: 185px;width: 205px;">
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.A address.Su" value="off">


<label style="position: relative; left:290px; top: 90px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox.A address.Sn" style="z-index: 1;position: relative; top:4px;">Snow<img src="https://stuff/Images/thumb.jpg" style="position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0;height: 185px;width:205px;">
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.A address.Sn" value="off">

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<label style="position:relative; top: 60px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox.A address.Wo" style="z-index: 1;position: relative; top:4px;">Women<img src="https://stuff/Images/thumb.jpg" style="position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0;height: 185px;width:205px;">
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.A address.Wo" value="off">


<label style="position:relative; left: 130px; top: 60px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox.A address.Mu" style="z-index: 1;position: relative; top:4px;">Music<img src="https://stuff/Images/music_thumb.jpg" style="position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0;height: 185px;width:205px;">
</label><input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.A address.Mu " value="off"> 


<label><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox.A address.Subscribe"></label>
<div style="position:relative; left: 50px; bottom: 33px;">Subscribe</div>
<input type="hidden" name="CheckBox.A address.Subscribe" value="off">


        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up" style="width: 280px;
    height: 45px;
    display: block !important;
    outline-style: none !important;
    outline-width: 0px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-family: 'itc_avant_garde_gothic_ltbold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #434242;
    background-color: #434242;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#434242), to(#2f2e2e));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #434242, #2f2e2e);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #434242, #2f2e2e);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #434242, #2f2e2e);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #434242, #2f2e2e);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bbb;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bbb;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 40px 0;">


</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. Screen shots below.

Labels are floating off when i minimize :

[image: Labels are floating off when i minimize]

Works fine when full screen :

[image: Works fine when full screen]

Comment: Perhaps adding `min-width` property to container (i assume it'll be body tag) may be a quick fix (but horizontal scrollbar will appear if window width is less than min-width of container). Also I strongly advise to do a proper styling and not inline because making any changes to layout even now is a time-consuming task. P.S. also i would suggest not to use `div` inside `label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented with a few bad practices and falsehoods on another answer, so I really had to make a quick example myself, this is one way to do it with flexbox (there are a lot of solutions to this problem, this is a good one if you don't have to support obsolete browsers):

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/um6fm744/1/

CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.interests {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.sub-header {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  width: 100%;
}

.interest { 
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 12px 24px 0;
  min-height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
}

.interest-info {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justity-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.interest-checkbox {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.interest-label {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  flex: 1;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 12px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="interests">
    <h1 class="sub-header">Interests:</h1>

    <div class="interest">
      <div class="interest-info">
        <input class="interest-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="interest-label">SKATE</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="interest">
      <div class="interest-info">
        <input class="interest-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="interest-label">SNOW</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="interest">
      <div class="interest-info">
        <input class="interest-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="interest-label">WOMEN</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="interest">
      <div class="interest-info">
        <input class="interest-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="interest-label">SURF</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="interest">
      <div class="interest-info">
        <input class="interest-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="interest-label">MUSIC/ART</label>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I appreciate the different ways of going about the fix.

Comment: One more thing, can you make the image still clickable to check the box as well?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you could take an approach like https://jsfiddle.net/um6fm744/2/ (note the js- classes to seperate js from html/css)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use inline styling.

I would tackle it more like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeEXEv

HTML:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item1">
    <button class="add-button">+</button>
    <span class="description">box 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item2">
   <button class="add-button">+</button>
   <span class="description">box 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item3">
   <button class="add-button">+</button>
   <span class="description">box 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item2">
   <button class="add-button">+</button>
   <span class="description">box 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item3">
   <button class="add-button">+</button>
   <span class="description">box 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item1">
    <button class="add-button">+</button>
    <span class="description">box 1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.items > li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.items .description {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.items .add-button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.item1 {
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/586137164188004352/wTK4hjbl.jpg);  
 }

.item2 {
   background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3276050019/f1d244a9f3254f30176922985c761d28.png);
  }

.item3 {
   background-image: url(https://people.rit.edu/~bmd6715/230/exercises/images/cat.png);
  }
```

Comment: The bit about it finding it's first relative parent element is untrue of course, you might want to edit that.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'm going to have a look at this now.

Comment: It's absolutely imperative that I have the little check box in the corner too. Will that still work?

Comment: You can just add two elements within an li-element and position them however you want the same way...

Comment: A lot of things are wrong or bad practice in this answer, absolute positioning relates to the first positioned ancestor, not relative, see: https://jsfiddle.net/xvqu1ndp/ - secondly it doesn't go to the body element, but the html element as it is the first ancestor, again se jsfiddle - thirdly you shouldn't style on IDs as the ruins the specificity, especially with a overly complex selector as '#items li span', there is no need to float layout either, that only creates issues, go display: inline-block for old browsers if you need, otherwise use flexbox.

Comment: What I meant was that an element with style position: absolute positions to the element above with styling position: relative.
It is indeed better to use classes than ids, but I made a quick example here to make a point.
I do still prefer using floating boxes instead of inline-box, but yeah flex would probably be better for modern browsers.

Comment: It doesn't position itself to the first ancestor with "position:relative" , that is not true (first statement), your second statement now is at the very least a quasi-truth (1 example with no real explanation), and that isn't helpful for someone learning, it positions to the first positioned ancestor element, be it "absolute", "relative" or other - float vs display is a somewhat personal opinion, but float always brings more trouble (need to add extra bloat to clear, etc.)

Comment: (My point is that a "quick incomplete bad practice example" doesn't really help someone trying to learn even if it solves their issue)